# DevOps Pipeline suddenly failing to access artifacts nuget feed. Unauthorised

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a problem that has randomly started happening today whereby all my DevOps Pipelines can no longer access my NuGet feed, which is a DevOps Artifact.

I have a task that is responsible for installing AzureSignTool, below is the YAML for that. I am using the `windows-latest` image on a Microsoft hosted agent.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install AzureSignTool'
  inputs:
    script: |
      set DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true
      dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool --version 4.0.1
```

This is the task that is failing with the following error.

> Unhandled exception: NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException:
> Unable to load the service index for source .  --->
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not
> indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

I have checked the permisisons on the feed and I can confirm that `Project\Build Administrators` are set as owners.

I have also tried various other things including changing the version of NuGet on the agent, changing the version of AzureSignTool etc.

What permissions / settings should I check?

### Update

So I moved the RestoreNuGetPackages task before the InstallAzureSignTool and this task succeeds, so clearly it can authenticate without issue.

However the task still fails. I have even added the `--ignore-failed-sources` but this had no effect.

The error message has changed, but the underlying issue is the same.

```
[NuGet Manager] [Info] GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/azuresigntool/index.json

[NuGet Manager] [Info] GET https://{ORG}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{GUID}/nuget/v3/registrations2-semver2/azuresigntool/index.json

[NuGet Manager] [Info] Unauthorized https://{ORG}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{GUID}/nuget/v3/registrations2-semver2/azuresigntool/index.json 767ms

[NuGet Manager] [Info] OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/azuresigntool/index.json 1010ms

Unhandled exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

### Further update

Switching image from `windows-latest` to `windows-2019` has resolved the problem so whatever changes Microsoft have done to the latest image are problematic. However this is not an ideal solution as we have VS2022 paths for TextTransform in the project file so the build fails later in the process.

How can I raise this issue with the appropriate team at Microsoft?

Comment: We are facing the same issue with nuget feed unauthorized suddenly in our azure devops pipelines. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Ryan, the task shared doesn't have DevOps artifact related. Do you have nuget.config in your project? Please check which account is used, and if the token is expired. Please use command `dotnet nuget list source` to list the current sources before your install sign tool task, and temporarily disable it via `dotnet nuget disable source sourcename` in pipeline. In addition, there is an public [incident](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/443741549).

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Thanks for your comment. I do have a NuGet.config in my project. The task above is the one failing, I believe it tries to install the AzureSignTool from NuGet but as one of the feeds fails to authenticate instead of carrying onto the next feed the whole task just fails.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Also just to note, unfortunately I cannot disable the problematic feed as it is required in a later task to restore NuGet packages for the solution.

Comment: @RyanThomas, if you use the user `Project\Build Administrators` to access the DevOps feed, please check if the token is expired. If not, please check for the two [scoped idenity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities), make sure they have contributor role on feed. If all are OK, it's recommended to check again after the incident above fixed.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT The above has now been cleared and the issue still exists, please can you advise how to check the tokens?

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Please see updates, is there a way I can raise this with the team at Microsoft as this is a breaking change :(

Comment: @RyanThomas, we notice others reported similar issue recently, could you please check the answer below by @crasht3st?

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Whilst the answer is useful it is not suitable for me as my problem is with a CmdLine task to install AzureSignTool, not related to publishing. Packages restore fine. The `dotnet tool install` does not have a no-restore option and the ignore-failed-sources argument does not appear to have any effect.

Comment: We have raised this as an Azure Pipelines ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/4556

Answer (score 2):

I am having an issue as well suddenly. Maybe this can help someone else. I fired off a build on the 10th and it worked just fine then I ran a build yesterday and it failed even though I had no code changes or settings changed either.

My issue was: *Unable to load the service index for source*.  This was due unauthorized access to the URL specified in the nuget.config because the implicit restore that takes place in the publish task cannot access authorized feeds. (*Weird, since it was working before.*) Although, I did notice that there was a change recently pushed to the virtual machine image I'm using (windows-latest).

My workaround was to add --no-restore argument to the publish task and add a explicit restore task prior to the publish task. It builds fine now.

Here is what those two steps look like now.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '{yourFeed}'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: {websiteName}'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--no-restore'
```

Here is what I had before:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: {websiteName}'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
```

Comment: thanks - same exact situation here too - running previously successful builds failed and everything. clearly a new hosted agent update issue - although i already had the explicit restore on the `sln` a step or two above. just adding the `--no-restore` to my publish stepped solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I'm glad it is helping others, unfortunately as you say a little different to mine. I have updated my question with some additional findings.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have a found a workaround, not a solution as this is an Microsoft issue for sure with the agent image.

I have added a separate NuGet config file with no other feeds in and I pass that file as an argument to the dotnet tool install command line task. Full YAML of the task provided below.

Also to note the `--ignore-failed-sources` argument which according to the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install) should `Treat package source failures as warnings.` I think should be enough on its own, but this appear did not work, so potentially another Microsoft issue.

```
#Temporarily added a seperate config file due to issues with windows-latest image.
#The ignore-failed-sources argument does not appear to function correctly.
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install AzureSignTool'
  inputs:
    script: |
      set DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true
      dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool --version 4.0.1 --ignore-failed-sources -v d --configfile NuGetTemp.config
```

UPDATE:

I also found another work around, after comparing the recent changes in the image, it appears changes were made to add .NET 8, so changing the pipeline back to use .NET 6 / .NET 7 also fixed the Install AzureSignTool task. My project is .NET Framework so there were no other drawbacks to this change. Below is an example of the task added.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '7.x'
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharing!  Yes, if you are using NuGet.exe to do the restore for a subsequent "dotnet" operation, you must use the matching version of NuGet.exe for the .NET SDK that you're using. Currently nuget version on 2022 is `6.7`, which is matching 7.0 .NET SDK. Check link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-6.7. So you can specify Dotnet version to 7.x to fix the error. You can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as it shows the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I upgraded a project from .Net6 to .Net8. My workaround uses two Nuget.Config files. The productive standard Nuget.Config file and a SimpleNuget.Config file just for installing/updating the AzureSignTool. The SimpleNuget.Config file is contained in the same folder as the SimpleNuget.Config file.

The '--configfile' argument selects the nuget config file that should be used.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Update Azure SignTool'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'update --global AzureSignTool --version 4.0.1 --configfile SimpleNuget.Config'
  continueOnError: true
```

My SimpleNuget.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding another answer. This is the same approach I took in mine. Annoying but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

@RyanThomas, thanks for letting us know it works after changing agent from Windows-latest to `Windows-2019`, and the workaround shared with `--ignore-failed-sources`.

However, i tried to follow your steps, and the task is working with `Windows-latest` agent on my side， please check the details below:

Step1: Add nuget.config, i added DevOps feed, public nuget source and credential inside.
[image]

Step2: I created yaml with nuget restore task before AzureSignTool install.

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: nuget restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'


- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install AzureSignTool'
  inputs:
    script: |
      set DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=true
      dotnet tool install --global AzureSignTool --version 4.0.1
```

[image]

Check the image used in pipeline log, the image is `fv` started, and version is  `20231115.2.0`, please check if it's same with yours.

And please try to add the credential in nuget.config for a check.

[image]

Edit:

Can reproduce the error 401 if i remove credentical on nuget.config, and use feed on nuget restore task.

[image]

You can report the issue on agent [link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues).

Comment: The image used is `Current image version: '20231115.2.0'` We have never had the credentials in the NuGet.config file, ever, and it has never caused a problem. My understanding this should be handled by the fact the Project Build Service has permissions on the artifact feed. Just to add I also do not use a NuGetToolInstaller task as this already there on the image.

Comment: @RyanThomas, i remove credential from nuget.config, in nuget restore task choose feed  instead. I can reproduce the 401 error. But if i put the credential back, it's all working.

Comment: Has something changed in NuGet auth with the latest image? I have never had to put credentials in the in the NuGet config file before, nor do I want to, isn't that the entire purpose of the Build Service user in DevOps?

Comment: Yes, i suppose there's some change on nuget or dotnet on image which caused the issue. And Build service account should work. You can raise a ticket on link [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues) to track it. I will update the reply with this. Thanks.

Comment: Believe it or not, I am a developer without a GitHub account haha. Would you be willing to create a ticket with all the appropriate details on my behalf?

Comment: I would also hazard a guess the problem is within the dotnet command, as the restore NuGet packages task works perfectly fine.

Comment: Believe the issue is within dotnet (.NET 8 specifically) please see the update on my anwser

Comment: We're also experiencing the same issue, do you have the link to the issue raised in the azure pipelines github? As I'd like to add a +1 to it. It's clearly a broken image - hopefully somebody at MS is working on a fix.

Comment: @SimonGregory, no new ticket raise yet, as confirmed, if you are using NuGet.exe to do the restore for a subsequent "dotnet" operation, you must use the `matching version` of NuGet.exe for the .NET SDK that you're using. Currently nuget is 6.7 which match 7.0 .NET SDK. Need to specify 7.x in task `task: UseDotNet@2`, you can check above answer from @RyanThomas, i also commented there.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT were using dotnet restore task (not nuget). I think the point is that an update to the windows-2022 agent has broken all our existing build pipelines (and others in this thread). So it's something related to one of MS internal hosted agent updates (likely .Net 8) so MS really needs to identify and fix the root cause. A workaround is just that, a temporary solution and an inconvenience particularly as we have 100 build pipelines which just stopped working overnight! Are we to go through and change them all!?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue with a hosted agent (also windows-latest). But the OS is windows 2022. Any clues on that?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't keen on entering credentials in the Nuget.Config file as suggested by @wade-zhou-msft so instead **I removed the reference to the "problematic" NuGet feed altogether.**

The NuGet.Config file I edited was:
*%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config*

Our pipeline was falling over the 'Install Azure SignTool' step as it was trying to access our Artifacts Feed. The point is, it shouldn't have to do that at this step, since it's restoring the required NuGet packages for the solution right after:

[image]